# Packaging pygame python scripts for cross-platform

Tags: python, pygame, packaging

What is the best way to package python scripts using the pygame module as cross platform executables? I need to be able to compile from my Linux machine. I've tried using PyInstaller, however, when I run the compiled executable, it says it can't find the pygame module. When I running it as a python script through the Wing IDE debug it works fine, so I clearly have pygame installed. However, when I try running without the IDE debug it fails to create a windows. Is there something wrong with my script that it can only be run through Wing IDE? How can I package my game so that it work on any computer, Linux or Windows, without even needed python or pygame? Is this even possible?

My source: https://github.com/william1008/TrappedTux

Comment: I see a few issues in your source. How does Pyinstaller nkow to package any dependencies that your applicaiton uses? I see no requirements.txt or setup.py or a pyinstaller spec file. You need to invest in some proper packaging to even get remotely portable.

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely new to python. I'll look into that, do you know of any good tutorials?

Comment: [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) -- Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller works fine to build a Windows executable that embed both python and pygame.

Here is the spec file I'm using:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['MyApplication.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)

# Remove some weird error message
for d in a.datas:
    if 'pyconfig' in d[0]: 
        a.datas.remove(d)
        break

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          Tree('resource', prefix='resource', excludes=[]),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='MyApplication.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=False,
          icon="resource/image/MyApplication.ico")
```

This will bundle everything (resources as well) into a single executable. However, you'll need to use `sys._MEIPATH` to access those resources. I use this code to detect automatically which path to use:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    return relative
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using cx_Freeze, it’s relatively easy to use and supports both windows and OS X